# How can I control which coins to spend in a transaction?

Tags: transactions, privacy, coin-selection, fragmentation, coin-control

When creating a bitcoin transaction, you have to choose which coins to use in them. The standard client does this [in a way](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-does-the-bitcoin-client-determine-which-coins-transactions-wallet-stored-va) to avoid unconfirmed inputs and minimize the number of inputs and amount of change involved. Since [not all coins are created equal](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/are-bitcoins-inherently-fungible), I may have other preferences (like spend unconfirmed coins first to get rid of them, or not cross inputs between different trading partners). Is there any way I can have more control over the process?

Comment: I suppose a workaround/partial solution is to use multiple wallets. Then you can keep coins apart, but also cannot make "large" spends.

Comment: related: [What does Bitcoin Core's "Coin Control Features" do and how do I use it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37486/5406)

Answer (score 3):

Currently this is not possible with the standard client, other than making separate wallets. There is [a patch for coin selection on github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/415), which was very promising. So this feature may make it into a future version.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Bitcoin Core has had a Coin Control feature for more than five years which allows manual input selection.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, so answers are outdated. Anyone reading this now: bitcoin-qt has coin control features that let you choose whichever txin you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Armory](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=56424.0), a new client that

> uses an algorithm for coin selection which can be optimized for
>   anonymity or minimal transaction fees.

Comment: armory looks pretty awesome. still pre-alpha though.