# What does Bitcoin Core's "Coin Control Features" do and how do I use it?

Tags: bitcoin-core, coin-selection, coin-control

What is Bitcoin Core's "Coin Control Features"?

How do I use it, and what can I do with it?

[image: Coin Control Features screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the "Yet another Coin Control Release [CLOSED]" BitcoinTalk thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=144331.msg1530422#msg1530422):

> **What is coin control?**
>   When you send bitcoins to someone else, the bitcoin client chooses kinda randomly which of your addresses will send the coins. With coin control you can exactly choose, which of your addresses will be the sending addresses. And even more specific which of your unspent outputs will be the sending inputs.

Comment: This is in Bitcoin Core, now.

Comment: Any idea how to use coin control features using the JSON RPC commands?

Comment: @VivekTeega Not automatically. When constructing transactions from scratch on the command-line, you have to choose addresses and compute amounts all manually. See [_Mastering Bitcoin_ (1st ed.), § "Using Bitcoin Core’s JSON-RPC API from the Command Line", §§ "Creating, Signing, and Submitting Transactions Based on Unspent Outputs"](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch03.html#_creating_signing_and_submitting_transactions_based_on_phrase_role_keep_together_unspent_outputs_phrase).

Answer (score 3):

When making a payment, Bitcoin Core will [automatically pick an input set](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5406) to fund the transaction. The **Coin Control** feature allows the user to perform the input selection manually instead. Explicitly selecting the input set can boost privacy by preventing [undesired address linkage](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy#Common-input-ownership_heuristic) and allows simple UTXO management tasks.